# validating extensions in multiple file uploader not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a multiple file uploader which should check for `-c.doc,-c.DOC,-c.Doc,-C.docx,-C.DOCX,-C.Docx`

If there is any other file other than these extensions it should show and error message and it should clear the selected files in that fileuploader I had referred the below code but its not working.

**The problem** is when I select files in this way `123-c.doc,345-c.doc,123.wamv,768-d.doc` it is accepting and showing that valid format but actually it should be invalid format.

How to resolve this?

```
function checkFileExtension() {
  var chkFile = document.getElementById('<%= filDoc.ClientID %>');
  var label = document.getElementById('<%= lblerrmsg.ClientID%>');
  var myfile = chkFile.value;

  if (myfile.indexOf("-c.doc") > 0 || myfile.indexOf("-C.DOC") > 0 ||
      myfile.indexOf("-C.doc") > 0 ||
      myfile.indexOf("-c.DOC") > 0 || myfile.indexOf("-c.docx") > 0 ||
      myfile.indexOf("-C.DOCX") > 0 ||
      myfile.indexOf("-C.docx") > 0 || myfile.indexOf("-c.DOCX") > 0) {
    label.innerText = "Valid Format";
  }
  else {
    label.innerText = "Invalid Format";
    chkFile.value = "";
  }
}


<asp:FileUpload ID="filDoc" runat="server" multiple="multiple" onchange="javascript:return checkFileExtension();"/>
```

Comment: In your code it will say it's valid if it finds at least one occurence of a valid format, which your example string contains.

Comment: then how can i do this it should not take other than -c.doc,-c.DOC,-c.Doc,-C.docx,-C.DOCX,-C.Docx

Comment: you'll have to split the value list into individual filenames, then make a loop to check each filename individually to see whether it ends with one of those valid strings, if it doesn't then stop the process and show the error message. If you get to the end of the loop and they all have a valid filename, only then show the "Valid Format" message.